# Show cursor for non focused edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I looking for solution to create blinking cursor to be visible even if edittext is not focused.

No idea so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Focus change listener and OnFocusChange keep the edit text activated.

I assume e2 and e1 be two text views:

```
 et2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                if(et2.hasFocus()){

                    //et1.setCursorVisible(true);
                    et1.setActivated(true);
                    et1.setPressed(true);

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give below property to your edit text for showing cursor .

```
edtTxt.requestFocus();
```